# Why does msgrcv returns ENOMSG

Tags: c, linux

System V message queue is created successfully, command `ipcs -q` outputs:

```
 ------ Message Queues --------<
 key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    
 0x080b2fb4 0          hel         600        0            0
```

But the program to receive the message returns:

> exit: msgrcv error, No message of desired type

This is my code:

```
/* create key for message queue */
key = ftok("/home/hel/messageQueueSystemV", 8);
if (key == -1) {
    printf("exit: ftok error, %s\n", strerror(errno)); // error
    exit(0);
}

/* open existed message queue */
mqFd = msgget(key, 0600);
if (mqFd < 0) {
    printf("exit: msgget error, %s\n", strerror(errno)); // error
    exit(0);
}

/* receive a message */
if (msgrcv(mqFd, &buf, 1 + sizeof(short), 0, IPC_NOWAIT) < 0) { // type is 0
    printf("exit: msgrcv error, %s\n", strerror(errno)); // error
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe there isn't a message waiting?  Where did you write the code to send the message to the queue?

Comment: Firstly, I run a program to create message queue and send a message. Then use cmd ipcs -q to check whether it succeeds. Then I start another process to receive that message.

Comment: The output of `ipcs` says there are no messages queued.  You told `msgrcv()` not to wait, so it didn't, so it returned "there are no messages queued".  What am I not understanding?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Thanks! How can I mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: See my answer.  You can't accept comments directly as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments to an answer.*</sup>

I suggested:

> Maybe there isn't a message waiting? Where did you write the code to send the message to the queue?

The response was:

> Firstly, I run a program to create message queue and send a message. Then use command `ipcs -q` to check whether it succeeds. Then I start another process to receive that message.

And quibbling began:

> The output of `ipcs` says there are no messages queued. You told `msgrcv()` not to wait, so it didn't, so it returned "there are no messages queued". What am I not understanding?

And, it appears, this was the correct diagnosis.